# Как сделать угловой блок?

Tags: css

Приветствую.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать верхний блок угловым?[image]

Comment: Какой div каким образом? Air, конечно, догадался какой и помог вам, но всё равно, пожалуйста, допишите уточнение прямо в вопрос

Comment: А можно узнать что это за полоски? Это типа линейка на шаблоне в фотошопе?

Comment: Да. Могу перезалить скрин.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: @Qwertiy, @Иван  вечно забываю о поддержке предупредить`

Comment: @Air, второе уведомление не придёт.